# TIFF image prints fuzzy (but works fine from Paint.Net)

Tags: c#, printing, tiff

I have created a TIFF image from several lines of text, and it's quite large at 300DPI.  The image itself looks pretty good.  The font is set as followings when drawing the string to the image:

```
drawing.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;
drawing.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
```

When I print the image, the text comes out fuzzy (I'm printing to a low-rez printer).  But, if I take the exact same image and print it from Paint.NET, it prints beautifully.  The difference is that when I hit Print in Paint.NET, it asks me if it should sharpen the image for printing -- when I say yes, that's when it works.

My question is what the heck is Paint.NET doing to sharpen the image and how do I mimic that?  I will post some code later tonight to assist with an answer, if anyone has an answer.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a .NET C# library called AForge.NET. It has many components and one of these components is an imaging library that does, indeed, have a sharpen filter (among many other types of filter). You can download the library here: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

And if you need help on how to use it, look here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx

Comment: It didn't do quite what I was looking for, but I'm going to mark this as the answer because that library is actually pretty cool and with source code is very interesting to peruse.  It made the image print a little sharper, but it just wasn't quite what I wanted.